# VideoView Невозможно воспроизвести видео

Tags: android, java

Добрый день! пытаюсь воспроизвести видео с флешки

```
 VideoView myIntroView = (VideoView) this.findViewById(R.id.myvideoview);
 MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
 myIntroView.setMediaController(mc);
 myIntroView.setVideoPath("/sdcard/test.mp4");
 myIntroView.requestFocus();
 myIntroView.start();
```

Android пишет "Невозможно воспроизвести видео"
Отлаживаю на устройстве! ЧЯДНТ?

Comment: может mp4 не проигрывается?))

Comment: может путь неполный указал? ты уверен, что видео файл подхватывается?

Comment: mp4 взял который советуют. Сначала думает пару секунд, потом показываются кнопки управления и исчезают и сообщение об ошибке, когда путь не верный по другому себя ведет! Всякие способы перепробовал, чужие примеры компилил, такой же эффект!

Comment: это ты все делаешь в UI потоке?

Comment: Да! А не надо?

Comment: Не надо =)

Comment: Напиши решение. У меня такая же проблема.

Comment: Ответ мой выше!

Comment: Это фактически не является ответом на вопрос. Если у Вас есть другие вопросы, Вы можете задать их нажав кнопку "[Задать вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)". Дополнительно Вы можете [добавить вознаграждение](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties), чтобы привлечь к вопросу больше внимания, когда Ваша [репутация](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет достаточного уровня.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело было в кривом кастоме! Прошился другим, заработало!

Answer (score 1):

на планшете у меня вот так заработало.

myIntroView.setVideoPath("/mnt/extsd/test.mp4");